# PLS-00222: no function with name 'LV_RATING_AGENCY_TAB' exists in this scope

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am still in school and learning PL/SQL, so be kind.
I am trying to create a range for loop that reads the collection contents and updates the RATING_AGENCY_ID column in the item table by checking the ITEM_RATING and ITEM_RATING_AGENCY column values with the members of the collection’s composite object type.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c IS
        SELECT a.rating_agency_id AS id
             , a.rating AS rating
             , a.rating_agency AS agency
        FROM   rating_agency_table a;

    -- Create a collection of rating_agency
    lv_rating_agency_tab rating_agency;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c LOOP
        lv_rating_agency_tab := rating_agency( rating_agency_id => i.id
                                             , rating => i.rating
                                             , rating_agency => i.agency );
    END LOOP;

    FOR i IN 1..lv_rating_agency_tab(i).COUNT LOOP
        INSERT INTO item
        ( rating_agency_id
        , item_rating
        , item_rating_agency )
        VALUES
        ( lv_rating_agency_tab.rating_agency_id
        , lv_rating_agency_tab.rating
        , lv_rating_agency_tab.rating_agency );
    END LOOP;
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, but I am getting the following error:

```
FOR i IN 1..lv_rating_agency_tab(i).COUNT LOOP
            *
ERROR at line 18:
ORA-06550: line 18, column 13:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'LV_RATING_AGENCY_TAB' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Should that be `lv_rating_agency_tab.count` rather than `lv_rating_agency_tab(i).count`? A bit of a guess as I don't have your table and type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

i'm correction your code.. let you try.. because i don't know abut your table & Type structure, so you can try this below code.. if any difficulties please let me know.

**code :**

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c IS
        SELECT a.rating_agency_id AS id
             , a.rating AS rating
             , a.rating_agency AS agency
        FROM   rating_agency_table a;

    -- Create a collection of rating_agency
    lv_rating_agency_tab rating_agency;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c LOOP
        lv_rating_agency_tab := rating_agency( rating_agency_id => i.id
                                             , rating => i.rating
                                             , rating_agency => i.agency );
    END LOOP;

    FOR i IN 1..lv_rating_agency_tab.COUNT 
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO item
        ( rating_agency_id
        , item_rating
        , item_rating_agency )
        VALUES
        ( lv_rating_agency_tab(i).rating_agency_id
        , lv_rating_agency_tab(i).rating
        , lv_rating_agency_tab(i).rating_agency );
    END LOOP;

    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

Tables & Type:

```
CREATE TYPE rating_agency AS OBJECT
(
   rating_agency_id NUMBER,
   rating NUMBER,
   rating_agency VARCHAR2 (100)
);
/
create table rating_agency_table
(
   rating_agency_id NUMBER,
   rating NUMBER,
   rating_agency VARCHAR2 (100)
);
/
create  table item 
(
rating_agency_id NUMBER, 
item_rating NUMBER, 
item_rating_agency  VARCHAR2 (100)
)
```

Block:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c
   IS
      SELECT rating_agency (a.rating_agency_id, a.rating, a.rating_agency)
        FROM rating_agency_table a;

   -- Create a collection of rating_agency
   TYPE typ_rating_agency IS TABLE OF rating_agency
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   lv_rating_agency_tab   typ_rating_agency;
BEGIN
   OPEN c;

   FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO lv_rating_agency_tab;

   CLOSE c;

   FOR i IN 1 .. lv_rating_agency_tab.COUNT
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO item (rating_agency_id, item_rating, item_rating_agency)
              VALUES (
                        lv_rating_agency_tab (i).rating_agency_id,
                        lv_rating_agency_tab (i).rating,
                        lv_rating_agency_tab (i).rating_agency);
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM ITEM;

RATING_AGENCY_ID ITEM_RATING ITEM_RATING_AGENCY
---------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             111           1 FFFF
             222           2 XXX
```